# find the minimum value in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, min

Lets say i have two columns as follows :

```
Column A        Column B
apples           1.2
apples           1
bananas          2
oranges          2.3
oranges          2.1
oranges          2.4
```

In another sheet, I've got apples/bananas/oranges in a column and I want to look up only the minimum value for each. I tried vlookup but it gives me the absolute minimum of all only once. I know I'm missing something here any help?

Comment: You can use the `FILTER` function to limit your table to just the relevant fruit.

Comment: This is also quick work for a [pivot table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MINIFS()` Function, --> **Excel Users** --> **MS365/Excel 2021/2019**

[image]

• Formula used in cell **F2**

```
=MINIFS($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,E2)
```

If not using any one of the above version of Excel then use the below

• Formula used in cell **G2**

```
=MIN(IF(E2=$A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7,""))
```

The above formula needs to press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` based on Excel version.

Comment: For Microsoft 365 users can use `=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A6),y,MINIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,x),CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))` at one go.

Comment: Problem is `VSTACK()` , `HSTACK()` is not available for regular users yet. Only available for insiders. New formulas are really great.