# worksheet has 2 columns. For each distinct value in column A, I want the minimum value from column B

Tags: excel, minimum

Imagine I have a 2 column spreadsheet. It has ~50,000 unique values in column A. There is a total of about 1,000,000 rows in the worksheet. In column B there is a timestamp. For each unique value in column A I would like to find the lowest value in column B.

e.g.

```
ColA |  ColB
AAAA |  15:00
BBBB |  14:30
CCCC |  22:19
AAAA |  14:59
AAAA |  15:01
```

I would like to return the values:

```
AAAA | 14:59
BBBB | 14:30
CCCC | 22:19
```

Regardless of the number of values exist for each unique column A value

Comment: Use `MINIFS()` Function

Comment: I agree that seems like the right function. However I just discovered that my company's version of Excel doesn't support it :-(

Comment: Then use `MIN()` with `IF()` or, you can use a `Pivot Table`, place the `Col A` values in `Rows Area` and the `Col B` in `Values Area`, next right click on the `Col B` and `Summarize` as `MIN` and set format as `Time` since date & times are stored as numbers in excel it will return as decimals so need to format it as time, `hh:mm;;;`

Comment: Refer this link [find the minimum value in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72673596/find-the-minimum-value-in-excel)

Comment: What is your excel version? Do you have `AGGREGATE()` function?